# Example of non-reduced Noetherian dimension 1 Cohen-Macaulay ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, noetherian, cohen-macaulay

As the name suggested, is there a non-reduced Noetherian dimension 1 Cohen-Macaulay ring? I know that all reduced Noetherian ring with dimension 1 is Cohen-Macaulay, however it seems difficult for me to create a concrete example of non-reduced Cohen-Macaulay ring with dimension 1.

Comment: $k[x,y]/(x^2,xy)$.

Comment: @Mohan that has an embedded point and therefore is not Cohen-Macaulay.

Comment: Sorry, I clearly misread 'non CM'.

Comment: Take any Artinian non-reduced ring $A$. Then $A[x]$ is $1$-dimensional non-reduced CM ring.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about this ring: $k[x,y]/(x^2)$?

Comment: The deletion of this fine answer frustrates me. It has historically been true that hints toward a solution are fine, so long as the solution is correct, and this answer is correct. The OP could certainly ask questions in the comments if they are confused. Anyway, I hope it is not deleted again. In the meantime, +1.

Comment: @user26857 Thank you very much for such a nice and simple example!